# Display documentation in Company results

Tags: company-mode, rust, racer

The GitHub page for `emacs-racer` shows function signatures in company completion results.

[image: https://github.com/racer-rust/emacs-racer/raw/master/images/racer_completion.png]

My results display "Function" and nothing beyond.

[image]

I've searched through `customize-group company` and can't find any variables that seem to be relevant. How can I achieve the advertised behavior?

I do not believe the problem is with the `racer` command itself. It works as expected when invoked from the command line, and `eldoc-mode` displays correct signatures.

Comment: https://github.com/racer-rust/emacs-racer/issues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue occurs if `emacs-racer` and `company-racer` are both installed. They are distinct packages and are not compatible. Install only `emacs-racer` and the function signatures show up as expected.

Comment: Please, accept your own answer to mark this question as solved. Thanks in advance.