# display documentation and available methods for java

Tags: java, ide

Is there a way to configure emacs so that it displays available methods and documentation when typing "." on an object. Something similar to company-racer for rust as described [In this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22435/display-documentation-in-company-results)

My java config used to work, but it broke recently. I have not been able to make it work.

The code for it is as follows

```
;;; package --- Summary
;;; Commentary:
;;; simple utilities and configuration for java mode.
;;; Code:
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.java\\'" . java-mode-utils) 'APPEND )

(require 'subr-x)
(require 'java-imports)


(add-hook 'java-mode-hook
                    (lambda ()
            (define-key java-mode-map (kbd "C-c l") 'java-doc-string-field)
            (define-key java-mode-map (kbd "C-c y") 'java-imports-add-import-dwim)
            ))

(add-hook 'java-mode-hook #'lsp)

(use-package projectile)
(use-package flycheck)
(use-package yasnippet :config (yas-global-mode))
(use-package lsp-mode :hook ((lsp-mode-deferred . lsp-enable-which-key-integration)))
(use-package hydra)
(use-package company)
(company-mode 1)

(use-package lsp-java
  :config
  (add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'lsp)
  (setq projectile-indexing-method 'hybrid)
  (setq projectile-globally-ignored-directories
        (append '("build" ".idea" ".gradle" "target") projectile-globally-ignored-directories))
  (setq projectile-completion-system 'ivy))

(use-package dap-mode :after lsp-mode :config (dap-auto-configure-mode))
(use-package lsp-treemacs)

(use-package meghanada
  :init
  (add-hook 'java-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (meghanada-mode t)
              (setq-local company-backends '((company-capf :with company-yasnippet))))))

;; See customization below for where to put java imports
(setq java-imports-find-block-function 'java-imports-find-place-sorted-block)

(message "Java Mode Utils is loaded")
(provide 'java-mode-utils)
;;; java-mode-utils.el ends here
```